# Compose dynamic SQL string with psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, sql-injection, psycopg2

I use `psycopg2` in python (2.7.10) to connect to a postgresql DB. The docs are pretty clear about composition of dynamic SQL statements:

> Never, **never, NEVER** use Python string concatenation (+) or string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at gunpoint.

In `psycopg2` version 2.7 there's the new `sql` module to do this string composition in a way that's safe against SQL injection. I nevertheless don't understand how to properly construct a statement like:

```
import psycopg2 as ps

C = psycopg.connect(host='my_host', port=Port, database='My_DB')
cur = C.cursor()
schema = 'some_schema'
table = 'some_table'
SQL = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM "+schema+"."+table+";") # This is horribly wrong
SQL = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM some_schema.some_table;") # That's what the result should be
```

Comment: I liked your statement which is so so hilarious - "Never, never, NEVER use Python string concatenation (+) or string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at gunpoint."

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [`psycopg2.sql.Identifier`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html#psycopg2.sql.Identifier) to interpolate an identifier to a query, e.g.:

```
from psycopg2.sql import Identifier, SQL

query = SQL('SELECT * FROM {}.{}').format(*map(Identifier, (schema, table)))
print(query.as_string(conn))
cur.execute(query)
```

As per the linked documentation page, in `psycopg2` v2.8+ you can also pass multiple strings to `Identifier` to represent a qualified name, i.e. a dot-separated sequence of identifiers:

```
query = SQL('SELECT * FROM {}').format(Identifier(schema, table))
```