# Format Python dictionary objects with psycopg2 sql calls

Tags: python, sql, psycopg2

I'm using a python workflow that makes frequent SQL calls, with the SQL calls stored in standalone files and formatted using `psycopg2` identifiers. I'm trying to modify these calls using dictionary objects, but can't get the SQL calls to format correctly.

An example header of an SQL file would be:

```
with my_table as (
  SELECT DISTINCT ON ("column_A")
    left_table."column_b",
    left_table."column_c",
    {column_identifier}
    ...
```

In my Python script I call the following:

```
col_info = my_dictionary.entry
column_identifier = " ".join([f'left_table."{x}",' for x in col_info])
```

This looks exactly right, but if I include this in a call

```
sql_call = py2.sql.SQL(sql).format(
  column_identifier=py2.sql.Identifier(column_identifier),
  ...
  )
```

I receive a formatting error where the parsed columns all look like this:

```
"left_table.""column_d"", "
```

If I use `Literal` instead of `Identifier` then the SQL call transacts but produces a nonsensical output. I cannot use `AsIs` because other `Identifier` calls are used.

The only potential solution I have seen so far is where the entire SQL call is contained within `f""" ... """` but since there are multiple, long SQL calls, including them all in the Python script would be very unwieldy. Being able to format these simple lines would be a highly preferable solution.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at how they do it in : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46770201/compose-dynamic-sql-string-with-psycopg2

Comment: Why wouldn't they look like `"left_table.""column_d""` you did `'left_table."{x}",'` which double quoted `x` and then `py2.sql.Identifier()` which double quoted it again. Look at docs here [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html), in particular *class psycopg2.sql.Identifier ... Multiple strings can be passed to the object to represent a qualified name, i.e. a dot-separated sequence of identifiers.* . There are plenty of examples to show how to do this.

Comment: It's still unclear to me how to prevent the double quotes around the column names. For example, escaping isn't an option (`.\"{x}\"`)

Comment: Don't do this `column_identifier = " ".join([f'left_table."{x}",' for x in col_info])`. Look at the examples in the `sql` module link above and add the table/column names directly to the `sql.SQL().format()`. The table/column names will end up double quoted because that is what `sql.Identifier()` does. The result if done correctly will be `"column_d"` not `""column_d""`.

Comment: I've done that elsewhere, but here I'm looking for a solution where I can generate an Identifier where the number of columns called changes between scripts, which is why `left_table`  is part of the call

Answer (score 0):

A rough draft of what I think you are looking for:

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import sql
con = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test host=localhost  user=aklaver")

left_table = 'left_tbl'
table_name = 'some_tbl'
column_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']


q = sql.SQL("SELECT {} FROM {} JOIN {} ...").format(sql.SQL(', ').join(
            [sql.Identifier(left_table, col)  for col in column_list]),
            sql.Identifier(left_table), sql.Identifier(table_name))
print(q.as_string(con))

SELECT "left_tbl"."a", "left_tbl"."b", "left_tbl"."c" FROM "left_tbl" JOIN "some_tbl" ...
```